# how can i get two consecutive values from Iterator

Tags: java, collections, iterator

Here is my code that i tried to get two consecutive elements of Iterator.

```
public void Test(Iterator<Value> values) {
    Iterator<Value> tr = values;
    while (tr.hasNext()) {
        v = tr.next();
        x = v.index1;
        // u = null;

        if (tr.hasNext()) {
            u = tr.next();
            y = u.index1;
        } else {
            u = v;
            y = u.index1;
        }

        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

But still i am getting same values for x and Y.

What is wrong with this, i am getting the same value for the two variables x and y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ultimate problem is with the `while` statement.  Your code will not just grab the first two elements from the Iterator.  Rather, if there is an even number of elements in the Iterator, it'll grab the last two.  If there's an odd number of elements then **you'll get the same value for x and y**.  Specifically, the last element.

More fundamentally, the problem with your code is `u`, `v`, `x` and `y` are declared outside of your method.  I assume you're doing this because you don't know how to return more than one value.  If you need to return multiple values, return an array of elements, or return a custom container class.

Here's an example of how you can return in an array the two elements taken off of a given Iterator:

```
public static Value[] nextTwo(Iterator<Value> values) {
    return new Value[] {
        (values.hasNext()?values.next():null),  
        (values.hasNext()?values.next():null)
    };
}
```

Note that the second element of the returned array will be `null` if the Iterator only has one value left in it.  Both elements of the array will be `null` if the Iterator is empty.

Answer (score 2):

It looks fine. Your problem lies somewhere else. Probably `index1` of both are just the same? Or you have only one item in the iterator?

The following example

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
Iterator<String> iter = strings.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String first = iter.next();
    String second = iter.hasNext() ? iter.next() : first;

    System.out.printf("First: %s, Second: %s%n", first, second);
}
```

prints as expected the following

```
First: one, Second: two
First: three, Second: four
First: five, Second: five
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and example, but where could be the problem. can you check again my code, i have updated it.

Comment: This doesn't change things. I've already mentioned two possible causes of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use braces around your `else`, and avoid needless variable assignments:

```
    while (tr.hasNext()) {
        v = tr.next();
        x = v.index1;
        // u = null;
        if (tr.hasNext()) {
            u = tr.next();
            y = u.index1;
        } else {
            y = v.index1;
        }
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
```

This code will only give the same value for `x` and `y` if either two consecutive elements have the same `index1`, or there is no next value (odd number of elements).

On another note, are you sure your first line shouldn't be `Iterator<Value> tr = values.iterator();`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, But my method is like this

public void Test(Iterator<Value> values){
          Iterator<Value> tr = values;
while (tr.hasNext()) {
    v = tr.next();
    x = v.index1;
    // u = null;

    if (tr.hasNext()) {
        u = tr.next();
        y = u.index1;
    } else {
        u = v;
        y = u.index1;
    }

    

    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
}
}

But still i am getting same values for x and Y.

Comment: @tsegay: Don't pass the Iterator to the function.  Pass the object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated code doesn't change anything.  @BalusC's diagnosis is still correct.  The problem is not in this part of the code.

Possible causes include:

- You have one `Value` element or an odd number of `Value` elements in the iterator
- You have `Value` elements with the same value for their `index1` in the list
- You have inserted the same `Value` element into the list multiple times.  (Maybe you forgot to use use `new Value(...)` to create each element?)
- You are using a custom `Iterator` class that is behaving incorrectly.

But without seeing the relevant code, we can only guess as to what the real problem might be.