# How to get n first values from an Iterator in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have sorted a `HashMap` using [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java) to that I have a `LinkedHashMap`, i.e. an `Iterable` which garantees iteration order.

Now, I'd like to retrieve a `java.util.List` of the first `n` entries of the map with a one-liner, if possible with a Java 8 Collection Stream API-technique.

I found [how can i get two consecutive values from Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432872/how-can-i-get-two-consecutive-values-from-iterator) which explains that there's a possibility to do that with an array, but that's not elegant, differs from my intention to get a `List` (although that can be transformed, but it's an unnecessary step) and requires an extra method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Stream the `entrySet` and limit the `Stream` to the first `n` elements:

```
List<Map.Entry<Key,Value>> firstN = 
    map.entrySet().stream().limit(n).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing more concise code with [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
List<Map.Entry<Key,Value>> firstN = EntryStream.of(map).limit(n).toList();
```